# How can we customize APActiveProjectAttribute() selector attribute located in APTran

Tags: selector, acumatica

I want to add a column in the Project Selector as shown in the screenshot.

The issue I have is how to find the selector code in the website files and how to add the column for APActiveProjectAttribute()

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PXCustomizeSelectorColumns` attribute.

The code can be generated by Acumatica Customization Project Editor with the `SELECTOR COLUMNS` action in the `DATA ACCESS` section:

[image]

This is the code it will generate. I added OwnerID at the end as an example. You can add your department column in the desired order. Note that Department should be in the PMProject DAC (if custom field that would be a PMProject DAC extension) for it to be available in that selector.

```
using PX.Data;

namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
    [PXNonInstantiatedExtension]
    public class AP_APTran_ExistingColumn : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
    {
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
        [PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
        typeof(PX.Objects.PM.PMProject.contractCD),
        typeof(PX.Objects.PM.PMProject.description),
        typeof(PX.Objects.PM.PMProject.status),
        typeof(PX.Objects.PM.PMProject.customerID),
        typeof(PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName),
        typeof(PX.Objects.PM.PMProject.ownerID))]
        public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI hugues. I was able to bring Department code but i want to display the description too. Client cannot recongnise with department by its code alone. they require Description field too. How can I bring that Description which is in other table.   Can you please help me out of this.

Comment: I don't know the exact field names but you can create a new custom field decorated with PXDBScalar attribute to fetch the description. [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<Department.descr, Where<Department.departmentID, Equal<departmentID>>>))]